# Can I join the Dark Brotherhood if I've already killed Grelod the Kind before 'Innocence Lost'?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've killed Grelod the Kind in Riften because of how she spoke to the kids. And I found the quest (Innocence Lost) that is supposed to let you into the Dark Brotherhood. Well I've already killed Grelod. What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. If you kill Grelod and then go talk to Aventus Aretino, the kid who sends you on the quest in Windhelm, he will say "I knew the Dark Borhterhood were good...but..". He will then proceed to give you the same reward as before, which is 100gp. The Brotherhood will contact you later.

*Info taken directly from the Skyrim Wiki and personal experience*